# Pre-load Images as background images in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, image, preload, image-preloader

In url_rec i am getting url of images. I want to pre-load images as background-image on browser before displaying it. We are fetching images which are currently being processed. So whenever i want to display any image it won't take any delay, and my work don't get slower. I am working on angular 5 and this code is written in .ts file.

```
this.socket.on('url_json', function(url_rec)
    {
      // console.log(url_rec);
    });
```

Html5 canvas to display backgrond image.

```
<canvas #myCanvas width="2048" height="2048" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + url + ')','background-repeat':'no-repeat'}">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Try by first making the images smaller using tinyimage. (Google tinyimage) this takes an image and makes its size smaller by optimizing colour palettes. This does decrease image load times dramatically.

Comment: Won't it decrease the clearity of image? I also need to zoom image for further refrences.

Comment: It really doesn&#39;t do that much damage to the image. You would be surprised. It does indeed cause some pixelisation... But minimal. Give it a try? It&#39;s quick and easy to use. I'm currently using it for an e-commerce website that I am developing.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do it? i am using canvas to display images. And images are continuosly arriving and changing. Above i have shown how i am using canvas.